# How to get value from a repeater in server side on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server">
                         <HeaderTemplate>
                         </HeaderTemplate>
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <tr>
                                 <td width="15%">
                                     <b>Subject</b>
                                 </td>
                                 <td width="60%">
                                     <%#Eval("Title")%>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
```

I do databind to a repeater, and bind the title value.

```
 string MysqlStatement = "SELECT Title, RespondBy FROM tbl_message WHERE MsgID = @Value1";
        using (DataServer server = new DataServer())
        {
            ..        }
        rptList.DataSource = ds;
        rptList.DataBind();
```

How can I get the value of title in server side, when a button in clicked in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the title in a server control, like a label, and then you can do something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then in the code behind:

```
int itemIndex = 0;

Label lbl = rptList.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
if (lbl != null)
{
    string labelValue = lbl.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the value of title to the text of a label that you could call FindControl() on.